# Как ловить все пакеты в Wi-Fi сети?

Tags: wifi, wireshark

Здравствуйте, мне нужно проанализировать пакеты в беспроводной сети.

У меня ОС Ubuntu 14.04, и я использую Wi-Fi маршрутизатор для выхода в интернет.

Когда я начинаю захватывать пакеты в Wireshark, я захватываю только те пакеты, в которых IP-адрес отправителя/получателя — IP-адрес моего компьютера.

Как мне ловить **все** пакеты в радиусе действия Wi-Fi маршрутизатора?

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я знаю, обычно Wi-Fi карточка и работает именно в таком режиме — отдаёт своей машине только пакеты нужные ей, т.е. с её IP. Поэтому сначала нужно её перевести в режим мониторинга. Например, для известного пакета утилит Aircrack-ng это делается так:

```
$ airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Известно, что не все Wi-Fi карточки переключаются в этот режим (нужно смотреть списки совместимости, например с тем же aircrack).

Также [вот](https://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#q6.1) ваш вопрос в FAQ по Wireshark.

И [вот здесь](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) ещё смотрите блок "Turning on monitor mode".